# SQL Plus. Don't show query results if execution was with error

Tags: sql, batch-file, output

I have .bat file which runs .sql file:

```
conn x/x@x

Set echo off



ACCEPT i_Number Number PROMPT 'ADD Number: '

spool C:\Files\data.txt

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE 
EXEC package.procedure (i_number=> &i_number);

Set termout off
Set verify  off

Select * from X
Where id = &i_number;

Spool off

Set term on
set head off
Select 'Chek file output data.txt' from dual;

pause
Exit
```

If procedure successfully completed then I have output from select statement. And that's OK. But if execution have error then I get error code and query result. In error I don't want query result, only error code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WHENEVER SQLERROR` command to do just that. Lot's of examples on how to use this in [oracles documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm).

Comment: And were i have insert WHENEVER SQLERROR?

Comment: @Inoracle before the SQL.

Comment: OK. If I want to add text to command line after execution 'Check file output.txt' (check updated code) whenever exit sqlerror isn't a good idea, because it's auttomaticaly exit from command line.  I want press enter, then exit from command line.